# Is it possible to store different id (of same type) inside one row?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm using laravel 8. In my database, I've this :
[image]

In my form, I have at least 2 or more checkbox of type `theme_id` (which is a foreign key inside my table). I need to put in my database the ones which are checked. Is it possible for me to store several `id` inside `theme_id` like this `1,4,8` ?

I did not find any documentation about this.

Cordially

Comment: You can store like that with one row. But its a bad practise. Even It will impact your query performance. I recommend you to make an another table called `theme` or something, where you store 1, 4, 8 with 3 rows

Comment: I do have a `theme` table. Inside it, there is all the name of the theme. But one article can have 1, 2 or more theme. What I need is a table between those 2 tables right ? Like `themes_articles` with inside it 2 foreign keys `id_article` and `id_theme` right ?

Comment: `themes` and `articles` should have pivot table and `belongsToMany` each other methods in corresponding models. Other than that, if project is in starting phase I suggest to reconsider renaming columns (i.e. in articles table there should be id field - not id_article and then you will use eloquent's code by default like a breeze). You can find recommendation naming in docs but also take a read of [this](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices). Following this, you'll avoid like 90% of unforced issues.

Comment: I'll read it. Thanks !